# Tag thousands of photos on a network drive

Tags: photo-editing

I have 6 thousand photo's and videos on a shared drive I would like to put tags on. Adobe Bridge doesn't seem to work across the network. Also I am looking for something where I can set up all the tags and as I have a photo in view I can click all the appropriate tags and then move on to the next one.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: By tags you mean metadata?  Bridge should work over local network but then network drives can be notoriously difficult.  Sounds like you want some kind of AI to tag your images for you.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if we have better knowledge of your objectives and expectations. For instance: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "tag"? - Are you speaking of EXIF/owner/creator data in the file's metadata collection? - Are you referring to simple watermarking/stamping the collection? - Are you looking for a means of automatically identifying the contents of the images for indexing to a stock site? - Are you attempting to locate all the human faces in the collection and run a facial recognition sweep? What operating system (Windows? Mac?) are you using? What is your objective wi

Answer (score 1):

That quantity of photos should drive you appropriately crazy if you try to do too much yourself.  Here's a few ideas.

If you store your photos on Google Photos, they will be auto tagged in the background (I don't think it's possible to directly download them with tags though).  In my Google Photos, I can search anything and it will pick up a lot of really good matches, all using AI.  Never tagged a thing.

From what I can see, Excire Foto does exactly what you want.  https://excire.com/en/  It will analyse images with AI and suggest tags automatically which you can click to add.

For more power, look into ImageKit.  It also leverages AI to tag images, but can be extremely powerful.  You can set up commands to auto tag images as they're uploaded to your storage.